Relative Git path in VS Code portable
Running VSCode portable 1.90.2, Git portable 2.45.2
I currently have a folder structured like so:
Drive D
|-- folder
|   |-- code
|       |-- ...
|       |-- Code.exe
|   |-- data
|       |-- PortableGit
|           |-- cmd
|               |-- git.exe

In Code, I had it set to git.path": "../data/PortableGit/cmd/git.exe.
When it came back, the Git log outputted:
2024-06-25 02:21:17.613 [info] Log level: Info
2024-06-25 02:21:17.613 [info] Validating found git in: "../data/PortableGit/cmd/git.exe"
2024-06-25 02:21:17.614 [info] Using git "2.45.2.windows.1" from "../data/PortableGit/cmd/git.exe"

And nothing but git clone works, erroring Git: spawn ../data/PortableGit/cmd/git.exe ENOENT when I proceed to initiallize a repo (it appeared as a dialog, but it is not actually logging)
error
This is all resolved when I put in the real path, but since this folder is going everywhere with my drive, I don't want to keep it like that and edit then reload every time I use it on the go.
Any solutions?
I have changed locations of both VSCode and Git, tried another computer, reinstalling Windows (if that helps) but all in vain.
